# Redirect ports on Apache

Tags: php, redirect, port

I have installed on my machine the following settings:

- Ubuntu 14.04 Lts Server
- Apache

But I have two web applications running on my server they are:

- Phpipam (running on port 80)
- Ethercalc (running on port 8000)
- Apache (running on port 80)

I recently had to use ProxyReverso to be able to redirect the Ethercalc to 80. whereupon my setup:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ProxyPreserveHost On
    ServerName localhost
    LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
    LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/
    ProxyRequests Off 
    ProxyPass / http://192.168.1.32:8082/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://192.168.1.32:8082/
<Directory /var/www/>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride None
Order Allow,deny
Allow from all
</Directory>
<Location /teste>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride None
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/site1/.htpasswd
AuthName "Password Protected Area"
AuthType Basic
Require valid-user
</Location>
<Location /teste/edit>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride None
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
Allow from 192.168.12.31
</Location>
<Directory /var/www/phpipam>
Options FollowSymLinks
AllowOverride all
Require all granted
</Directory>
    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined


</VirtualHost>
```

When access my localhost, it redirects to the Ethercalc, but I would like that when I type for example: https://localhost:81, I am redirected to the Phpipam.

Does anyone have any idea if this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can using two virtual hosts, but you do not have to use the portnumber for it. You have normally two IP addresses at your disposal, namely 127.0.0.1 and 127.0.1.1. Use one for the PHPiPam and the other for EtherCalc. Then you do not have to use a proxy.

Now are you redirecting all your requests redirecting to Ehtercalc. You only have to do that for requests that start with for instance www.ethercalc.te.

You set both domains (www.ethercalc.te and www.phpipam.te) in your /etc/hosts file, create two virtual hosts for them, enable them and you are ready to go.

In Apache you have a port.conf. In that file can you add port 81 as a port on which Apache should listen. You can create a virtual host for port 81 and then map that to your PHPipam server.

In my file /etc/hosts have I set the first entry to:
    127.0.0.1   localhost    www.tandt.lb tandt.lb

This is the virtual host:

```
<VirtualHost www.tandt.lb:80>
    ServerName www.tandt.lb
    ServerAlias tandt.lb *.tandt.lb
    ServerAdmin lbergman@tandt.lb
    DocumentRoot /var/www/Websites/TestAndTools
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteOptions Inherit


    <Directory /var/www/Websites/TestAndTools>
        Options -Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride FileInfo
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/tandt/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel debug

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/tandt/access.log combined

    Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
    <Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
        Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from all
        Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
    </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

Make sure to create the custom log directories before enabling this virtual directory using a2ensite .... (your filename in the directory /etc/apache/sites-available).

Comment: Thanks for reply , could you make a VirtualHost example ? , please .

Comment: for example, you have another application that is located in var / www / test1 and want this directory is redirected to port 81.

how would you do this VirtualHost.

Another thing, I can not find the httpd.conf in my apache2.

etc / apache2 does not have it.
/ usr / local / does not have it.

just have the apache2.conf

Comment: You can not redirect from one port to the other within a virtual host. You can however catch requests on port 81 using virtual hosts by specifying the port in the definition of the virtual host. You will have to specify apache to listen on port 81 by declaring Listen 81 in ports.conf. That file is included in the configuration file of apache. In general is that httpd.conf, on Ubuntu apache2.conf. Your apache2.conf is therefor the same file as the httpd.conf.